# Why haven't modern browsers made the DOM data stream / state driven to support modern web applications *without a framework* yet

Tags: dom, browser

With Web Components and custom elements now standardized and a part of all modern browsers, it seems those same browsers should be capable of a natively implemented reactive DOM by now. Why is there no native reactive DOM in modern browsers?

Comment: What do you call a reactive DOM?

Comment: Perhaps I should probably clarify my question like this: Why isn't the DOM reactive by default in modern browsers? Or, why haven't modern browsers made the DOM data stream / state driven to support modern web applications *without a framework* yet?

Comment: Yes you definitely should clarify your question, with real and clear examples of features you think browsers should implement but haven't yet. Because there are many features to react to DOM changes, and many ways to batch DOM changes in unobtrusive ways. But that's our job as web devs to use it in the proper way.

Comment: @Kaiido, sure we can use a framework like React with a virtual DOM, or we can build a virtual DOM ourselves... My question is more to the question: Why should we have to? Why hasn't the DOM changed to support data streams and state management natively yet?

Comment: Well it does support "state management" natively.For instance all <input> do change their `.value` at user input and trigger events you as a developer can hook on. And almost all the DOM is more or less reactive in the same way. Virtual DOM is natively supported, all offscreen manipulation can be thought as being done in a Virtual DOM. We even have DocumentFragments. And the heavy part of the DOM update (layout and rendering) are already batched by the browsers in clever means. For "data streams" I'm not sure what you are talking about.

Comment: "Data stream", I suppose, means one-way data stream or state management. Server knows about an update to a value -> Client gets the updated value -> DOM updates only the one web component that needs that updated value it needs instead of refreshing the entire DOM to populate the change. That's my understanding of what React does.

Comment: Using React is not an answer to my question.